# Outputting two bash loop result values to the same line?

Tags: bash

I have a log file saved on my computer which i wish to create a script to parse.  My aim is to pull two values from each line of the log file and then output them, next to each other (perhaps hyphen delimited) on the same line and then iterate through for each line within the log.  For example, the following logs:

```
123-abc-thething01, 6, 1234, metadata, metadata, email1@email.com, metadata, 123abc
123-abc-thething02, 6, 1234, metadata, metadata, email2@email.com, metadata, 123abc
123-abc-thething03, 6, 1234, metadata, metadata, email3@email.com, metadata, 123abc
```

After running the script will hopefully achieve...

```
123-abc-thething01 - email1@email.com
123-abc-thething02 - email2@email.com
123-abc-thething03 - email3@email.com
```

At the moment, I have the following code which is pulling the correct values, however it is simply outputting all of 'var1' and then all of 'var2' as shown below, rather than go through line by line, outputting var1 and var2 values for line 1 on a single line, then var1 an var2 for line 2 on a new line E.T.C.

```
123-abc-thething01 123-abc-thething02 123-abc-thething03
email1@email.com email2@email.com email3@email.com
```

I have spent some time trying different ways of doing this but I am a bit stumped.  I am not very strong with bash at the moment so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in logfile.txt
do
   var1=$(cat logfile.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/,//g')
   var2=$(cat logfile.txt | grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*')
done

echo ${var1}
echo ${var2}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use shell scripts to parse text files, for instance this could be done using only awk `awk -F, '{print $1" -"$6}' file`

Comment: Given your updated requirement you could also use perl `perl -ne 'print "$1 - $2\n" if /([^,]+).*, ([[:alnum:]._-]+@[[:alnum:]._-]+)/'`

Comment: Thank you! Thats handy I think I will go with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r -a array
do
  # remove leading white space from element 5
  echo "${array[0]} - ${array[5]/# /}"
done < logfile.txt
```

Output:

```
123-abc-thething01 - email1@email.com
123-abc-thething02 - email2@email.com
123-abc-thething03 - email3@email.com
```

If possible use awk for this job.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, thanks for this It is really helpful!  I should have probably mentioned tho, that the email addresses can be at any position within each log line and are not just at position 5 (my bad).  This is why i wanted to use regex, but would you happen to have a suggestion in this circumstance? Thank you

Comment: Why would you change a short, efficient awk script to a while read loop?

Comment: @Dronzil The only part of an email address that can be reliably matched with a regex is the `@`. Anything else you put into an email regex has the potential to fail on valid addresses. If this is handling real world addresses that users submit, then you really need another way of tracking which field the address is at.

Comment: @ccarton What email address don't you think you can match with regex?

Comment: @123 Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html. Maybe I should have said there is no simple regex. That article does mention some of the 'official' regexes but they are quite complex and the article does not recommend using them. Also, the common case is for validation. Identification can be harder.

Comment: @ccarton As explained in the link though, the first basic regex is enough for 99% of all emails, it really depends on what sort of data you expect to be receiving(or what you accept). Based off of OP's question though it appears that `@` only appears in the one field, and so just matching that character would probably be good enough in this case to identify the field the email is in on that line.

Comment: @123: hek2mgl showed a awk solution already (this was my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f64625b5-e476-4420-ae62-9594dc1c8b18/view-source)) and question is tagged with bash.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F', ' '{printf "%s - %s\n", $1, $6}' log.file
```

Comment: this will have an extra space before $6